# Name of current institution in a paper

Tags: publications, paper-submission, affiliation

I'm about to publish a paper with my previous group.

I'm not in a permanent position, and my boss doesn't care if I mention or if I don't mention my current institution in the paper.

For me, a researcher who wishes to have a permanent faculty position, would it be helpful or not at all to do that?

Comment: In physics, you would be with your old affiliation at the top of the paper, with a footnote to your 'current address'.

Comment: Yeah. I understand that. But is that something really important? Or no one really cares.

Comment: It is important to give the old affiliation as mentioned by @Jon Custer. But, the readers may like to reach you in future. So, it is wise to give the current one with a footnote saying that *present address*

Comment: Add a personal email address and URL, then readers can reach you, regardless of where you are.

Answer (score 1):

The work should be credited to the institute at which it was done - this is important for citation and publication metrics, and will be pulled out of the metadata of the publication by several services. The author is a separate entity to the institute which employed or supported the author. A subsequent change in affiliation - for contact details, *e.g.* - should be taken care of in a footnote in the front matter.